# Modelagem banco No-SQL

Tags: firebase, nosql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que usara angular para a parte de front-end e o firebase para o banco de dados.
O Firebase usa um banco de dados No-Sql e estou tendo dificuldade para entender como eu posso modelar ele.
Por exemplo tenho dois nós, "solicitacoes" e "solicitacoes-user", dentro de solicitações tenho um campo que se chama "tipo" sera que eu devo criar mais um nó com "solicitacoes-tipo" para ficar mais rápido e fácil de filtrar, ou terá muitas informações repetidas ?

Eu não entendi muito bem como deve ser feita a modelagem de um banco No-Sql quando eu devo criar um nó, se é normal repetir informações para não percorrer um no inteiro desnecessariamente, se alguém poder me explicar melhor

Comment: Sua dúvida tem a ver com isso? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data ou é específica para o modelo de negócio que você está criando?

Comment: sim, é referente a estrutura do banco, eu já tinha dado uma olhada nesse link que você postou, mas não tinha entendido muito bem, por exemplo, de acordo com esse exemplo não tem problemas de criar nós iguais em difirentes lugares, facilitando assim a busca, porem eu acho que fica mais difícil de criar, editar e excluir pois tem que mudar em vários lugares

Comment: Acho que entendi. A sua dúvida é mais geral no sentido de quais as melhores práticas para levar um modelo ER para uma estrutura de árvore de objetos como o JSON ao invés de levar para uma estrutura SQL, considerando a forma como o Firebase faz o acesso a esses dados.

Comment: isso mesmo,  eu trabalho com modelo relacional, usando bancos como mysql,  PostgreSQL, Oracle. Ao usar um banco NoSQL eu estou um pouco perdido ja que a estrutura é outra.

Answer (score 1):

Banco de dados No-SQL trabalham com uma ideia de desnormalização, a grosso modo 
 é repetir um mesmo valor para diversos nós. O próprio Firebase tem um canal no youtube que pode te ajudar. Me ajudou bastante a entender como modelar meu banco no Firebase.

Dá uma olhada nessa playlist deles, me ajudou muito.
[PlayList Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)